# Calling a method from a model in a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Super new to rails, but is it possible to call methods from a model in a migration?

Lets say I have a model that looks like:

```
class Orders < ApplicationRecord

   def order_size
      Order.where(item_id: 1).count
   end


   def order_level (order_size)
     if order_size =< 2
       Order.update_all(customer_level: "Bronze")
     elsif order_size >= 3 && order_size < 6
       Order.update_all(customer_level: "Silver")
     elsif order_size >= 6
       Order.update_all(customer_level: "Gold")
     end
   end

end
```

Could I run a migration that will only update certain size orders, such as:

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
       if order_size == 10
         (call/do order_level)
       end
    end
 end
```

Just for context, I've implemented a separate functionality that will automatically update an order's `customer_level` when a new order is created with `order_level`, but I need to go back and update all of the orders that already exist. I only really care about orders that are 10+ in this case.

Hope this makes sense and isn't completely ridiculous!

Thanks

Comment: Migrations should only be used for creating/altering the database structure, if you need to change data you can use write custom rake tasks or rails runner scripts

Comment: @Subash - I'm pretty much 100% on the same page with you. Sadly, the docs also state that *"Migrations can also be used to add or modify data."* I don't like the idea of it, but there it is.

Comment: `Order.update_all(customer_level: "Gold")` this has no limitation and will updated all `Order`s to `customer_level` "Gold". Please ensure you know what you actually want to do before releasing this into production

Comment: @engineersmnky - You're a better person than I. I was going to mention that the code looks seriously banged up and broken/dangerous. But, got lazy. Thanks for your diligence.

Comment: @engineersmnky Apologies, this was sloppy pseudo-code, I appreciate you looking out.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to call methods from a model in a migration?

Yes. As illustrated in [the docs, section 8 Migrations and Seed Data](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), you can call model methods in a migration. Here is the sample code from the docs:

```
class AddInitialProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    5.times do |i|
      Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
    end
  end

  def down
    Product.delete_all
  end
end
```

Whether it is a good idea or not is a separate question.